# Validation in primefaces datatable calendar cell

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have couple of Calendar columns in a datatable:

```
    <p:column headerText="Time From" >
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS" value="#{aa.timeFrom}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS" value="#{aa.timeFrom}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Time To">
        <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output">
               <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS" value="#{aa.timeTo}"/>
           </f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
               <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS" value="#{aa.timeTo}"/>
           </f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
```

And also a "submit" button:

```
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{aa.submit}" />
```

Calendar picker is displayed when mouse button is clicked in a cell. The user can either pick a date/time or enter a value in the cell. If an invalid value such as "123456" is entered and then mouse is clicked in another cell, the cell border is of the invalid cell is displayed as red and the following error message is displayed:

"'123456' could not be understood as a date and time. Example: 15/01/2018 11:54:02.247"

The submit action is called when the user clicks on "submit" button. The problem is that in the submit action, the invalid values returned are null and not the values entered by the user. The valid values are correctly set. How can I get the invalid values entered by the user in the submit action? In the above example, I would like to get "123456" instead of null.

If invalid values cannot be returned, then is it possible to find which cells have invalid values in the submit action? I want to distinguish between values not entered and invalid values entered (Both of the date/times are optional).

Comment: Please provide your PF version. I can't reproduce this with 6.1. When I enter `123456` as date and click into another cell, my input is simply ignored and delivers no error at all.

Comment: What do you mean by PF version?

Comment: The version of PrimeFaces you're using.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I am also using PrimeFaces version 6.1.

Comment: Can you add more details, like the `<p:datatable>` tag, maybe some events or event listeners are causing this? I will try to reproduce this. Or can you post a simplified version of `aa.java`?

Comment: The <p:datatable> tag is very simple with just `var="aa" value="myClass.aas" editable="true" editMode="cell"`. There are no events or event listeners. The aa.timeTo and aa.timeFrom are declared as Date.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce this, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that I am displaying datatable in a dialog.

Comment: Nope, no difference. Provide a *verifiable and minimal* example that can reproduce this issue and post the page and the bean, otherwise this question is useless. While you build a small example you may discover differences between the example and your production code - helping you discover the problem yourself.